# How to nicely handle [:-0] slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

In implementing an autocorrelation function I have a term like

```
for k in range(start,N):
    c[k] = np.sum(f[:-k] * f[k:])/(N-k)
```

Now everything works fine if `start = 1` but I'd like to handle nicely the start at `0` case without a conditional.

Obviously it doesn't work as it is because `f[:-0] == f[:0]` and returns an empty array, while I'd want the full array in that case.

Comment: Doesn't `numpy` already have an autocorrelation function? Or is it `pandas` only?

Comment: It has a `correlate` function I could maybe use but there are different definitions of autocorrelation, particularly with respect to the `(N-k)` denominator in this term.

Comment: I think pandas has autocorrelation where you can use different terms for denominator, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: not so clear from `pandas.Series.autocorr` docs, I will look into the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use negative indices in this case

```
f[:len(f)-k]
```

For `k == 0` it returns the whole array. For any other positive `k` it's equivalent to `f[:-k]`

Answer (score 2):

If k is zero use None for the slice, like so:

```
for k in range(start,N):
    c[k] = np.sum(f[:-k if k else None] * f[k:])/(N-k)
```

Comment: nice to know about `None`, but I wanted to avoid branching at all, guess @Wombatz solution is the cleanest and fastest one.

Comment: The difference in speed is likely to be swamped by other parts of your program, So use whichever idiom you find most readable.  (In my tests, the speed difference is only on the order of tens of nanoseconds).

Comment: Uh, you're right, given the big datasets I'm working on I thought an unneeded `if` would be noticeable, but I just tested and it actually is not. Probably it gets optimised away. Still I prefer the other solution, will give a +1 to yours as soon as I get to 15 points :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it, by testing if `k==0` before applying the formula. It's up to you to find the only that looks nicer.

```
for k in range(start,N):
    c[k] = np.sum(f[:-k] * f[k:])/(N-k) if k != 0 else np.sum(f * f[k:])/(N-k)

for k in range(start,N):
    end_in_list = -k if k != 0 else None
    start_in_list = k
    c[k] = np.sum(f[:end_in_list] * f[start_in_list:])/(N-k)
```